# The Radical of an infinite dimensional Lie Algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let ${\displaystyle k}$  be a field and let ${\displaystyle {\mathfrak {g}}} $ be a finite-dimensional Lie algebra over ${\displaystyle k}$. There exists a unique maximal solvable ideal, called the radical.

Can you give an example in infinite dimensional Lie algebra such that maximal solvable ideal does not exist?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2432511/96384