# Existance of Maximal solvable ideal of Lie algebra.

Tags: lie-algebras

**A Lie algebra has a unique maximal solvable ideal**

I could prove this fact for finite dimensional lie algebras using Zorn's Lemma. But couldn't figure out if this fact is true for any Lie-algebra in general or not.

I tried to mimic the same proof , but failed.
I took the set of all Solvable ideals of the Lie algebra (it is non-empty). This set is partially ordered by inclusion relation. In the finite dimensional case I could say every chain has an upper bound easily, but for infinite dimensional lie-algebra I could't say that!.. That's where I got stuck and hence could't apply Zorn's Lemma.

Help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The case of finite dimension usually is the one where one can do without Zorn's Lemma, and one can here. (This does not help for your case, hence this is just a comment.)

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1496755/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2432511/96384.