# Maximal solvable ideals in infinite dimensional Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

For finite dimensional Lie algebras we now that there exists a unique maximal solvable ideal. Now for infinite dimensional Lie algebras this breaks down because of the existence part. I have a rough idea on why that is true but i want to have a concrete example in mind. This has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2432511/the-radical-of-an-infinite-dimensional-lie-algebra) before but hasnt been answered, so i thought i'd bring up the question again.

Comment: See the paper by Togo linked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496755/radical-of-an-infinite-dimensional-lie-algebra). I think, it has also a counterexample in it.